# Vue: keep linebreaks and indentation intact

Tags: templates, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm working on a Vue app that (obviously ;)) loads Vue templates, lets the user fill in content and then export the markup of those templates/components. However, all linebreaks and indentation are lost in the process.

Is there any way to make Vue keep that information? So far at least I achieved to keep (conditional) comments via the

```
comments: true
```

option. There are several other options like `expectHTML` or `shouldDecodeNewlines`, but they don't seem to be documented and none of them seem to help me accomplish what I want.

The problem is that we're in part handling email templates (meh...) and it's a client requirement that "input === output" (well, markup-wise), because indeed a space or linebreak here or there can indeed make a difference in fussy mail clients. So simply running the markup through a beautifier is not an option.

I know, I know... That's not really what Vue is made for, and markup !== DOM... But the tool itself is written in Vue and I love to currently be able to use all the magic of Vue syntax inside the templates being processed as well.

If all else fails, I might have to resort to using mustache (or any other template system - recommendations welcome) - but I would really like to keep the templating as it is right now, for the aforementioned reasons.

Comment: how do you export ?

Comment: @JacobGoh using outerHTML on the element of the preview component

Comment: babel runs when you compile your project, but your create those templates during runtime, so babel or any other part of your build chain can't have any influence on this. You should probably share more details of what you actually do.

Comment: @LinusBorg right, should have probably mentioned that no build process is involved. The templates come from inside `<script type="text/x-template">` tags and are loaded into a preview component, so the template markup itself is not being created during runtime, just filled with texts and values. Imagine it as kind of a CMS.

Comment: I just found out that if I wrap the whole body content with a `<pre>` tag, the linebreaks and indentation are kept - so I think there must be a way to achieve this behaviour!